# Realloc chews up string array during recursive storage of dir/filenames

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I am using `opendir/readdir` in a C program (GNU on cygwin) to collect the filenames from some nested directories into a string array (the program uses largely C89 and earlier conventions). Since I don't know the number of files in advance I decided to use `malloc/realloc` to perform dynamic memory allocation. A pointer array is passed through recursive calls to collect filenames. The problem is that filenames stored during early calls to `getlist()` are being corrupted during later storage steps. After going into a subdirectory, performing a second call to `realloc` and emerging from the subdirectory, strings at the edge of the storage at the point after the `realloc` was executed are progressively corrupted as additional filenames are collected in the parent directory.

If instead I allocate memory using a single `malloc` assignment to create a large initial pointer array I avoid the problem, but I'd like to be able to use `realloc`. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong, specifically I guess it's how I am using `realloc` in this case?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

// function prototypes
char ** getlist(char ** filelist,long int *numfiles,char *dirname);

extern int stat (const char *filename, struct stat *buf);   
extern DIR * opendir (const char *_dirname);
extern  struct dirent * readdir (DIR *dirstream);

int main(int narg, char* argv[])
{ 

    // vars
    char * dirname;
    char **filelist, **traverse; 
    long int numfiles =0;
    FILE* pfile;

    //....................................
    // and go ...

    if ( (filelist = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)))  == NULL )
    { 
            printf("Fatal malloc error!\n"); 
            exit(3);
    }
    filelist = getlist(filelist,&numfiles,argv[1]); // argv[1] is dir name 

    // list the stored filenames and write to file

    pfile = fopen("listoutput.txt","w");
    printf("Stored filenames (N=%i):\n",numfiles);
    traverse = filelist;    
    while(*traverse)
    {
        printf("%s\n",*traverse);
        fprintf(pfile,"%s\n",*traverse);
        traverse++;
    }
    fclose(pfile);

    // free etc should go here...

    return 0 ;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

char ** getlist(char** filelist, long int *numfiles, char* dirname)
{

    // variables
    char filename[200];
    char dirname_[200];
    DIR * directory;
    struct dirent * file;

    strcpy(dirname_,dirname);

    // for checking file type
    // macro:   int S_ISREG (mode_t m)  
    struct stat* filestat = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
    int sizeofchar = sizeof(char); // fields: mode_t st_mode, unsigned char d_namlen

    char **traverse, **ptemp; 

    //aux
    long int ii, icheck;    

    // check number of valid files in dirname and allocate memory in char pointer array
    ii=0; 
    directory = opendir (dirname_); 
    while(file = readdir(directory))
    {
        sprintf(filename,"%s/%s",_dirname_,file->d_name);
        icheck = stat(filename,filestat);
        if (icheck==0)
        {
            if (S_ISREG(filestat->st_mode)) ii++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Couldn't check file type of file \"%s\"  (icheck = %i)\n", filename, icheck);
        }
    }

    // generate enough room for all the filename strings

    if ( (filelist=(char **)realloc(filelist,sizeof(char *)*(*numfiles+ii+1)))  ==  NULL )
    {
        printf("Fatal realloc error!\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    traverse = filelist + *numfiles; 

    // now store the filenames in filelist ...

    (void) rewinddir (directory);   
    while(file = readdir(directory))
    {
        sprintf(filename,"%s/%s",dirname_,file->d_name);
        icheck = stat(filename,filestat);
        if (icheck==0 && S_ISREG(filestat->st_mode))
        {
            *traverse = (char *)malloc(sizeofchar*(strlen(filename)+1));
            strcpy(*traverse,filename);
            traverse++;
            (*numfiles)++;

            // spit out what we have so far
            printf("\nCurrent list (looping):\n-----------\n");
            ptemp = filelist;   
            ii=*numfiles;
            while(ii--)
            {
                printf("%s\n",*ptemp);
                ptemp++;
            }
            printf("\n-----------\n");          

        //sleep(1); 
        }
        else if (icheck==0 && S_ISDIR(filestat->st_mode))
        {
            if (strcmp(file->d_name,".")!=0 && strcmp(file->d_name,"..")!=0 )
            {
                printf("Processing folder %s\n", filename);
                filelist = getlist(filelist,numfiles,filename);
                traverse = filelist + *numfiles; 

                // spit out what we have so far
                printf("\nCurrent list (returned from getlist):\n-----------\n");
                ptemp = filelist;   
                while(*ptemp)
                {
                    printf("%s\n",*ptemp);
                    ptemp++;
                }
                printf("\n-----------\n");

            }       
        }
    }
    (void) closedir (directory);

    *traverse = NULL;

    return filelist;    
}
```

Comment: Ideas: Code omits various error checking - perhaps that is catching up on this code.  Check `malloc/realloc` return.  Insure `sprintf(filename,"%s/%s",_dirname,file->d_name);` is of sufficient size, etc.  Also, in dynamic systems a rescan of a directory may yield more/less entires than the first.  Suggest checking that filename list is of sufficient size. Also might want to zero fill allocated memory.

Comment: BTW, the pattern `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...)` is a *very*, **very** bad practice.  If `realloc` fails, you will loose access to the original pointer and leak the associated memory.  Google for "realloc memory leak" for lots of reasons why.

Comment: @chux, So far no improvements, will keep chipping away. Might try performing the dir search twice, first time to collect the total number of filenames prior to a single malloc.

Comment: regarding this line in main(): char ** getlist(char ** filelist,long int *numfiles,char *dirname);  this line is only effective inside the main() function, and does not provide a prototype for the function located after main().  Therefore, the function after main() uses the compiler function default (return int, all parameters are int).

Comment: regarding this line:(and similar lines): strcpy(_dirname,dirname); the compiler often/usually places a leading underscore in names when creating the asm code..  I.E. such lines could easily become copy to self operations.

Comment: @user3629249 The code consists of 2 functions `main()` and `getlist()`.  The `getlist()` line in `main()` may not provide a prototype for following functions, but since the next function is `getlist()`, that declaration serves as a prototype for any subsequent `getlist()` calls and does not default to returning `int`.

Comment: @user3629249 I tested what you pointed out, so far no luck: moved prototypes out of `main()` and `getlist()`, changed naming of `_dirname` to `dirname_`

Comment: Somehow the iterative call messes up the data, with data stored at a higher stage somehow corrupting that stored at a lower one. Perhaps some vars should be declared `static`??

Comment: @TryHard - can you give us a (reasonably short!) example of the output? It would be interesting to see how the filenames have become corrupted. And are the results always corrupted, or only when you have a certain number of files / subdirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is AFAIK a working solution. It turns out I wasn't keeping proper track of the number of pointer array elements already allocated, and so during sequential calls to `realloc` I was effectively overwriting old memory locations with new data. It is surprising that the result of the bug was not more dramatic - accidental I guess.

My solution is to pass around a second `int` that keeps track of the number of strings (filenames) to store. I could alternately scan the pointer array at each level of recursion to determine this number on the fly.

Finally I wonder if it would not have been better to implement this as a linked list. Leave that for next time.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef struct stat STAT;


// prototypes
extern int stat (const char *filename, STAT *buf);  
extern DIR * opendir (const char *dirname);
extern struct dirent * readdir (DIR *dirstream);


char ** getlist(char ** filelist,long int *pnumfiles, long int *pnallocated,char *dirname);


int main(int narg, char* argv[])
{ 
    // vars

    FILE* pfile;
    char **filelist, **traverse; 
    long int numfiles, nallocated;

    //....................................
    // and go ...

    if ( (filelist = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)))  == NULL )
        { printf("Fatal malloc error!\n"); exit(1);}
    nallocated = 1;
    numfiles = 0;

    filelist = getlist(filelist,&numfiles,&nallocated,argv[1]);         // argv[1] should be a directory name

    // list the stored filenames and store to file

    pfile = fopen("listoutput.txt","w");
    if ( pfile  == NULL )
        { fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file for output!"); exit(4);};

    printf("Stored filenames (N=%i):\n",numfiles);
    traverse = filelist;    
    while(*traverse)
    {
        printf("%s\n",*traverse);
        fprintf(pfile,"%s\n",*traverse);
        traverse++;
    }
    printf("\nDONE!\n");
    fclose(pfile);

    return 0;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

char ** getlist(char** filelist, long int *pnumfiles, long int *pnallocated, char* dirname)
{
    // variables
    char filename[200];
    char dirname_[200];
    DIR * directory;
    struct dirent * file;

    // for checking file type
    // macro:   int S_ISREG (mode_t m)  

    STAT* filestat; // fields: mode_t st_mode, unsigned char d_namlen

    long int ifile = 0; // number of files to store from current dir
    int sizeofchar = sizeof(char); // = 1

    //aux
    long int icheck;    
    char **traverse, **ptemp; 

    // and go ....

    // copy string to const char array because opendir demands one

    strcpy(dirname_,dirname);

    if ( (filestat = malloc(sizeof(STAT)) ) == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory for filestat!"); 
            exit(2);
        }

    // check number of valid files in dirname and allocate memory in char pointer array

    directory = opendir (dirname_); 
    while(file = readdir(directory))
    {
        sprintf(filename,"%s/%s",dirname_,file->d_name);
        icheck = stat(filename,filestat);
        if (icheck==0)
        {
            if (S_ISREG(filestat->st_mode)) ifile++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Couldn't check file type of file \"%s\"  (icheck = %i)\n", filename, icheck);
        }
    }

    // generate enough room for all the filename strings

    *pnallocated = *pnallocated + ifile;
    if ( (filelist=(char **)realloc(filelist,sizeof(char *)*(*pnallocated)))  ==  NULL )
        {
            printf("Fatal realloc error!\n");
            exit(2);
        }
    traverse = filelist + *pnumfiles; 

    // now store the filenames in filelist ...

    (void) rewinddir (directory);   
    while(file = readdir(directory))
    {
        sprintf(filename,"%s/%s",dirname_,file->d_name);
        icheck = stat(filename,filestat);
        if (icheck==0 && S_ISREG(filestat->st_mode))
        {
            size_t size = strlen(filename) + 1;  // Add 1!
            if ( (*traverse = malloc(size)) == NULL ) 
            {
                printf("Fatal malloc error!\n");
                exit(3);
            }
            memcpy(*traverse, filename, size);  
            traverse++;
            (*pnumfiles)++;
        }
        else if (icheck==0 && S_ISDIR(filestat->st_mode))
        {
            if (strcmp(file->d_name,".")!=0 && strcmp(file->d_name,"..")!=0 )
            {
                printf("Processing folder %s\n", filename);
                filelist = getlist(filelist,pnumfiles,pnallocated,filename);
                traverse = filelist + *pnumfiles; 
            }       
        }
    }
    *traverse = NULL;
    (void) closedir (directory);    

    return filelist;    
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you should accept this answer (from yourself)! You are doing some good work here and learning as you go: but do you really think the OS memory handle in blocks is the issue here? All you are doing here is allocating more memory than you think you need... probably hiding the problem (till it bites you unexpectedly...) rather than solving it. Keep trying!

Comment: @AAT Thanks for your comment - I found the bug and rewrote my answer. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient memory allocated.

By not allocating enough room for the terminating null character and then performing a `strcpy()`, memory may get corrupted.

```
// *traverse = (char *)malloc(sizeofchar*strlen(filename));
// strcpy(*traverse,filename);

size_t size = strlen(filename) + 1;  // Add 1!
*traverse = malloc(size);
memecpy(*traverse, filename, size);
```

Minor:  No need to cast the return from `malloc()`.  Once code knows the size, use, `memcpy()` vs. `strcpy()`

--

Update

Rather than printing `ii` times, print until `*temp == NULL`.

```
 while (ii--) {
    if (*ptemp == NULL) break;
    printf("%s\n", *ptemp);
    ptemp++;
  }
```

`ii` is bases on directory size, yet usage of filenames does not include "." and "..".

Suspect code still has other problems but GTG.

Comment: Thanks - you are right about the 'strlen(filename) + 1'. Thanks also for the advice. Unfortunately this correction did not clear up the problem (!?)

Comment: Thanks again - I think the pointers and the local mem management are ok (I have tried strncpy, memcpy, memset - without improvement). As I write above, I think somehow the iterative call messes up the data, with data stored at a higher stage somehow corrupting that stored at a lower one because of a pointer salad. Perhaps some vars should be declared static??

Comment: A robust solution would not need static variables.

Comment: I found a "work-around". I don't call it a full solution because I am don't understand in detail why it works.

Comment: I got to the bottom of the problem... wasn't keeping proper track of the amount of memory already allocated, I posted an answer.